# Convert object into normal multidimensional php array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a php variable `$response` containing an object with protected keys:

```
FindCompletedItemsResponse Object (
    [searchResult:protected] => SearchResult Object (
        [item:protected] => Array (
            [0] => SearchItem Object (
                [itemId:protected] => 383198481839
                [title:protected] => Matchbox SCX SRS2 Jaguar "XJR-14" Super Racing Castrol #4 Slot Car 1/32 NIB
                [globalId:protected] => EBAY-US
                [primaryCategory:protected] => Category Object (
                    [categoryId:protected] => 4781
                    [categoryName:protected] => 1970-Now
                )
                [galleryURL:protected] => https://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mslyccjMA3BvwuDua4N-kkg/140.jpg
                [viewItemURL:protected] => https://www.ebay.com/itm/Matchbox-SCX-SRS2-Jaguar-XJR-14-Super-Racing-Castrol-4-Slot-Car-1-32-NIB-/383198481839
                [paymentMethod:protected] => Array ( [0] => PayPal )
                [postalCode:protected] => 923**
                [location:protected] => Fontana,CA,USA
                [country:protected] => US
                [shippingInfo:protected] => ShippingInfo Object (
                    [shippingServiceCost:protected] => Amount Object (
                        [attributeValues] => Array (
                            [currencyId] => USD
                        )
                        [value:protected] => 8.95
                    )
                    [shippingType:protected] => Flat
                    [shipToLocations:protected] => Array (
                        [0] => Worldwide
                    )
                    [expeditedShipping:protected] => 1
                    [handlingTime:protected] => 1
                )
                [sellingStatus:protected] => SellingStatus Object (
                    [currentPrice:protected] => Amount Object (
                        [attributeValues] => Array (
                            [currencyId] => USD
                        )
                        [value:protected] => 49.95
                    )
                    [convertedCurrentPrice:protected] => Amount Object (
                        [attributeValues] => Array (
                            [currencyId] => USD
                        )
                        [value:protected] => 49.95
                    )
                    [sellingState:protected] => EndedWithSales
                )
                [listingInfo:protected] => ListingInfo Object (
                    [startTime:protected] => 2019-10-07T18:28:15.000Z
                    [endTime:protected] => 2020-01-15T22:19:56.000Z
                    [listingType:protected] => StoreInventory
                )
                [returnsAccepted:protected] => 1
                [condition:protected] => Condition Object (
                    [conditionId:protected] => 1000
                    [conditionDisplayName:protected] => New
                )
            )
        )
        [attributeValues] => Array (
            [count] => 1
        )
    )
    [paginationOutput:protected] => PaginationOutput Object (
        [pageNumber:protected] => 1
        [entriesPerPage:protected] => 100
        [totalPages:protected] => 1
        [totalEntries:protected] => 1
    )
    [ack:protected] => Success
    [version:protected] => 1.13.0
    [timestamp:protected] => 2020-04-09T10:01:15.148Z
)
```

I would like to convert this to a normal multidimensional php array where I can access e.g. the title like `$response[0]["title"]`.

I tried `get_object_vars($response)` and `json_decode(json_encode($response), true)` but that is not doing anything when I am looking at the printed results.

and I tried this function:

```
  function o2a($obj) {
    if(!is_array($obj) && !is_object($obj)) return $obj;
    if(is_object($obj)) $obj = get_object_vars($obj);
    return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $obj);
}
```

but it just gives an empty array :(.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "protected keys"? Where does this output come from?

Comment: Well, according to the [documentation](http://devbay.net/sdk/guides/api/class-DTS.eBaySDK.Finding.Types.FindCompletedItemsResponse.html) of this class, it inherits a `toArray` method. Have you tried that?

Comment: `get_object_vars` won’t give you access to members that aren’t visible to you at that point, so you can’t get at the protected ones like that. You will either explicitly have to call the object’s getter method for those - or try casting to an array, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php#47075

Comment: @CBroe thank you for your answer. But what do I need to change for my function o2a to work with your argument?

Comment: @El_Vanja I am using this api sdk https://sdk.intradesys.com/

Comment: So it seems that InTrade is internally using eBay API, which means it should be returning that exact class I linked to. Have you tried the `toArray` method?

Comment: @El_Vanja I did: (array) $response. But the objects inside are still there. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No. Try calling the method `->toArray()` on the object to see if this is the right class.

Comment: @El_Vanja $response->toArray() results in: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method FindCompletedItemsResponse::toArray()

Comment: Alright, then it's not that class I linked. How exactly are you getting this response? When I test InTrade, it returns an XML response. Probably something in the SDK that's turning it into an object. Try to debug throughout the code.

Comment: @El_Vanja when you go to playground you can display the PHP code instead of the xml input that you just need to copy and paste. That is all I do.

Comment: The code shows a path for the request: `InTradeSys\eBay\finding\FindCompletedItemsRequest`. I'm guessing the response is `InTradeSys\eBay\finding\FindCompletedItemsResponse`, so try to open that file and see what sort of methods it offers.

Comment: @El_Vanja thank you for the hint. That file only contains the class constructor function.

Comment: Does it perform any logic in the constructor? If not, it must extend some other class, so check that one.